# How to decode peer list in binary model

Tags: binary, bittorrent, peer

I'm trying to make a python BitTorrent client, but I'm having some difficulties in understanding the tracker's answer: I receive something no-understandable (in bencode), and after I've decoded it using the bencode library, I've got this:

```
{'min interval': 1800, 'peers': 'N\xe7\x9b\xb1\x91\tS\x9e\x1e\\\x1a\xe1\\Xl4A\x17N}\xeb\xe2\xe7\x86R\xebS\xd9w:H\x0b\xa3\xf6\xddc[Ey\xae\xef\xf7\x02\x00&\x9e\x98\xcdR\xedyc\x126\\\x9c\xe9j2H\x02\x06\x95=\xd3\x83m\x11\x13r\xe1p]\x00\x98\xfe0=Z\x11i]X\xe4Z\x00\xad\x1fx?R\xfb\xe5\xc2\x1e#\xc5\xcd7e\x96\xbc[[\x0c\x05\xeam)\x88&f\x1a\xe1J8\x80)\xc5DS\xc0\xd20\x83"\xb4\xb4\x01\xbf\xc5D\\\x92\xcc\xa8)\xa2ilA\xec\xb9\xc0N\xef_N\xdf4\x9e\xffe\xa25gio?\x05\xb6iV\xd6tq\xeeZPvHl\xf7\xd9R\xf4\xff\xca~KY\\\xeb\xd5\xf63\xbcM*\x15T\xd3\xb0\xbd2\x18\x9aWP\x0c\xd5)PLYW\x00 y\xf3)R\x92/L\x0b\\\x91c$\x9e\x8bm\xd6\x95#@\x05X\x8a$\xb0Bc\x95\x9a\xcas\x1a\xe1M\x82\x07\x04\xb3_Z\x16\x93\xe5\xf1H\\\x86%\xe5V\x0c\xc5\xcd\xfbY\xd6\xb4\xaf\x9e\x97\xf2i\x1aR\xf5\xd3\xfc\x84UTf\xc9\'\xc8\xd5\xb0\xbd\'\x9b\xd5\x87QB6\xbe\x93pN\xed(\x86x\x0c', 'interval': 1800, 'complete': 1034, 'incomplete': 262}
```

How do I decode the ['peer'] item ? It sounds like it's binary-model encoded, but I can't find anything to decode it...

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [BEP 23 (tracker returns compact peer list)](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html).

Every 6 bytes is a peer, 4 for an IPv4 IP address and 2 for the port.

Comment: @sinicy well I don't know how Python handles its IP addresses, but I imagine you'd start out doing what you'd do in any language: construct the 32bit address and the 16bit port number from the bytes (remember they're stored in network order)

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know that, for example, \x1a=26 ? Is there a list or something that I could find ?

Comment: @sinicy I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: How do I translate \xdf\xf9\xfc\xc2\xa9\xbc into an IP adress ?

Comment: @sinicy 223.249.252.194:43452 probably, but I did that by hand and may have made mistakes

Comment: And how did you do that ?

Comment: @sinicy just converted the first four bytes to decimal, put the last two bytes together to 16bits where the last one is the low part.

Comment: But how do you do that ? Can you tell me where to find something that I could learn that with ?

Comment: @sinicy that's pretty basic, look up hexadecimal. Note however that if you did it in code, that wouldn't be required - in code you already have the bytes as bytes, not as strings in any particular base, that's just how they appear if you view them as string.

Comment: What do you mean ? I can't convert "\xd5\xdeZI\xb5\xa4X\xad\x8d" in an IP:Port with hexadecimal decoding... Or could I use the byte version as an IP adress ?

Comment: @sinicy they're really just 6 bytes, you're looking at them like characters and that puts in the weird \x escape sequence and so on. If you look at the data as an array of bytes (BEncoded strings *are* just arrays of bytes, and only rarely do they represent text) it will make more sense.

Comment: But what are the first our bytes ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding the code I used to have this:

```
    from bencode import *

debugModeActivated=False

import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.smartorrent.com:2710/announce?info_hash=%10Y%91%a5%fb%be18%ea%a2y%0c%95%98%de%20%e1%c1%bf%a1%10&peer_id=-TR2820-7ynd5qd1ct1g&port=51413&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=1476537925&numwant=80&key=24a78997&compact=0&supportcrypto=1&event=started")
trackerResponse= str(r.content)
if debugModeActivated:
  print"request result:", r.content, "\n"


trackerResponse=bdecode(trackerResponse)
print trackerResponse
```